# Hibernate: hbm2ddl doesn't set sequence.nextval as column default

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm running into a problem with mapping sequences to a column's default 
while using Hibernate's hbm2ddl to generate the database schema. After using hbm2ddl 
on a fresh database the generated SQL doesn't set a default value on the table. 
This causes problems when using anything other than Hibernate to issue insert statements.

The following java code details the troublesome entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_ROLE_ID", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
    public Integer getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }

    ...
}
```

The above generates the following SQL in the following order:

```
create table ROLE (ROLE_ID integer not null, primary key (ROLE_ID))
create sequence SEQ_ROLE_ID
```

Issuing an insert through Hibernate works as you'd expect but issuing an insert through SQL 
(E.G., `INSERT INTO "ROLE" (NAME) VALUES ('ADMIN');`) results  in a 
`NULL not allowed for column "ROLE_ID"` error message.

Is there anyway I can get the hbm2ddl to generate the following SQL in the following order?

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_ROLE_ID
CREATE TABLE ROLE (ROLE_ID NUMBER DEFAULT SEQ_ROLE_ID.NEXTVAL);
```

I am using the 4.0.1.Final version of Hibernate and H2 for the database.

Comment: Try to remove the attribute allocationSize=1 so that it would use the default and see what happens ?

Comment: Removing allocationSize and initialValue has no effect.

Comment: Setting strategy=GenerationType.AUTO seemed to work but hibernate just ignores the generator field and creates it's own generator.

Answer (score 2):

use "schema" in `@SequenceGenerator (for example: schema="public" )` and columnDefinition in `@Column`

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", columnDefinition = "int8 DEFAULT nextval(\'SEQ_ROLE_ID\'::regclass)")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "seq", sequenceName = "SEQ_ROLE_ID", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1, schema="public")
    public Integer getRoleId() {
        return roleId;
    }
```